# I keep getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have looked at the other threads. I am a longtime lurker, this is the first time I'm posting (I think) or it's been a while. Anyways, I know what the problem is, I think, based on the other responses, it would seem that my variable isn't initialized. But I don't think this is my issue.

I am trying to create a "Guess the word" game, similar to hangman without the stick figure. I am creating a function that sees how many times the letter is in the word. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Please look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong...?

Thank you!

```
function timesInWord(word, letter) {
  var re = new RegExp(letter,"gi");
  var isMatch = word.match(re).length;

if (isMatch != null && isMatch > 0) {
 return isMatch;
 } else {
 return "No Match, Try again!";
 }
}

console.log(timesInWord("Mississippi","r"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no match found `word.match(re)` returns `null`. Trying to call `length` on `null` causes the error.

You do not need to use `length` property. In your case only the `null` checking is enough. Try the following:

```js
function timesInWord(word, letter) {
  var re = new RegExp(letter,"gi");
  var isMatch = word.match(re);
  if (isMatch != null) {
   return isMatch.length;
   } else {
   return "No Match, Try again!";
  }
}

console.log(timesInWord("Mississippi","p"));
```

Comment: thank you. Now, since I have checked if it is null before trying the length, would I be able to do "return isMatch.length" ? I think that's how I was supposed to do it? Forgive me as I am a newbie, working on coding projects to get better.

Comment: @KiarraJ., of course you can do that. I have updated my answer to return `length`.....thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`word.match(re)` will return `null` if there are no matches. That's the cause of the problem. If you want to check if there are matches, before getting the length of the array, check if it's not `null`.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!